# AppController for AngualrDart&Flutter

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, dart, flutter, angular-dart

I am writing a project in `AngularDart` and `flutter`, which are sharing common codes. I have `AppController`, which will handles all the logic business codes, being used in most components:

```
class AppController {
  AppController(this.serviceOne, this.serviceTwo...);
}
```

Now I am writing `AngularDart`. I have two options:

1. Use DI, pass AppController, serviceOne, serviceTwo as providers into bootstrap. I am not sure whether I should mark these classes as injectable. And I heard that flutter doesn't quite support injectable. And I am a newbie in Dependency injection, not sure how to implement it.

**Code 1.1:**

```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    new Provider(
      AppController,
      useValue: new AppController(
        new ServiceA(),
        new ServiceB(),
        ....
      ),
    ),
  ]);
```

**Code 1.2:**

```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    AppController,
    ServiceA,
    ServiceB,
  ]);
```

**Code 1.3:**

```
  // From Günter Zöchbauer's answer
  createAppFactory(ServiceA sa, ServiceB sb) => new AppController(sa, sb);
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    new Provider<AppController>(
      useFactory: createAppFactory,
      deps: [ServiceA, ServiceB]          
    ),
  ]);
```

2. Pass into AppComponent and sub-components as `@input` level by level. This is simple but doesn't look elegant.

```
class AppComponent(AppController controller) {
}

class subComponent() {
     @input 
     AppController _controller
}
```

3. Other better options?

And I am also thinking, if we use appController to handle the business logic layer, and let the platform codes implement only the widget. The services are defined in the common codes. Can I just create the services inside appController and don't let platform codes touch it. In other words, platforms codes uses the common code only through appController, and the services are created internally in the appController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the `@Injectable()` annotation, you can't use the code in Flutter anymore because it ties the code to `dart:html` through Angular.

You need to create the service without `@Injectable()` and then add a wrapper for Angular with the annotation.

in `shared_code/lib/foo_service.dart`

```
class FooService {
  BarService bar; 
  FooService(this.bar);
}
```

in `angular_code/lib/foo_service.dart`

```
import 'package:shared_code/foo_service.dart' as shared;

@Injectable()
class FooService extends shared.FooService {
  FooService(BarService bar) : super(bar);
}
```

I think I saw it mentioned that the Angular team was discussing about whether they can get rid of `@Injectable()`. That would make this much easier.

Another way would be to use factory providers to not require `@Injectable()`

```
FooService createFooService(BarService bar) => new FooService(bar);
FooService createBarService() => new BarService();

providers: const [
  const FactoryProvider(FooService, createFooService, deps: const [BarService]), 
  const FactoryProvider(BarService, createBarService)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helps. I just read the angular-dart document, and see they are using useFactory which is the same as FactoryProvider. So can I implement the factory provider like Code 1.3? And I also add a question about whether to create services inside business logic layer? Lastly, createFoo should be createFooService in your code?

Comment: ’useFactory` is going to be deprecated as far as I know. 1.3 - yes. I don't really understand this last question. In Angular let DI create the services and in Flutter create it outside the appController and pass them in.

Comment: Angular dart team should update their documentation. Sorry, I update and clarify my last question above.

Comment: I find it hard to give a general answer here. I'd start with a small Angular and Flutter app and try it out to avoid surprises at a later stage of the project.

Comment: Thank you, please inform me if any findings. Maybe redux could make it easier to implement this structure. If it works, interestingly, that will make Angular just work like react.

Comment: I'm using Redux in an app where I share code between Flutter and Angular and it serves me well.